# Pass by reference C++ compilation errors

Tags: c++

Hello I am trying to parse an a class through a function. I need it to be read only and I have no need to edit it. So in order to do this I pass the object by reference using the const argument. But I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

```
 void Container::push_Object(const Module& input){
      cout << "Pushing object" << endl;
      input.print();
......
}
```

The class decleration and print function:

```
class Module{
private:
    short number;
    string* args;
    string pname;
    bool _isFact;
public:
    Module(string, bool, short, string);

    string* get_Items(){ return args; }
    string get_name(){ return pname; }
    bool isFact(){ return _isFact; }

    void print();

};


void Module::print(){
    cout << pname << "(";
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        cout << args[i] ;
        if (i != number - 1) cout << ',';
    }
    cout << ")" << endl;

}
```

I am working at VS 2013 and this is the error I get

> Error 15  error C3867: 'Module::print': function call missing argument
>   list; use '&Module::print' to create a pointer to member

Comment: Make sure that you don't `input.print` (without parentheses) somewhere in code. Copy and paste exact line where the error is produced.

Comment: Declare `print` as a `const` function

Comment: @NemanjaBoric this is the line I get it.

Comment: @AndyG yes that would work but isn't these 2 equivalent?

Comment: I'm wondering if `Error 15` is some internal code, or just the 15th reported error.

Comment: @JmRag: There is this notion called "const-cascading" where if one access point to a variable is `const`, then every operation on that `const` variable must also be `const` (to guarantee that the item doesn't change, else why pass it as `const` to begin with?)

Comment: @NemanjaBoric it is internal code. It is the first error I get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot invoke a non-const function on a const reference
change it to

```
void print() const;
```

Answer (score 2):

To call a method on a const object, the method it self need to be const. change line

```
void print();
```

to:

```
void print() const;
```

and it will work.
What this essentially means is that inside `print()` the `this` pointer is const so that `print()` can't change the object, maintaining its constness.